# Question on querying like select max(B) from t where A=123

Tags: mysql, select, indexing

I wonder how the MySQL will deal with the statement? If both Column A, B are indexed.

I suppose there will be two ways to do.

1. a. Select all records from t that A==123 as a temp result 
   b. find the max B one from the temp result and return. 
   The time complexity might be O(lgN + m).
2. Get the record in one step, in other word, T(N) = O(lgN)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My instinct would tell me that unless B is nullable and B is sparsely populated (really sparse, as low as 1% or lower as well as numbering less than 10% of the average number of values per index key A), such that inspecting B in descending order *then* checking for A=123 on those records is worthwhile, MySql won't have a bar of the index on B for this query.

More than likely it will just use A (if A is selective enough), retrieve from the table the records, sort by B descending and return the result.

This would mean your 1st case, O(N + m).  N is directly proportional to table size, which is also statistically how many records on average would satisfy A={any x}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, well, in my case, A can be considered as a foreign key, while B is a primary key. My teammate told me that if I create a multiple key on (A,B), it may be the 2nd one. Now I am doing some experiments.

Comment: It *could* be O(lg N + m) if your distinct values for A also increase whenever N increases, which means index key values don't grow as quickly.

Comment: yes, I found that if I create a multiple key on (A,B), the query 'select max(B) from t where A==123' will not cause a temp result set.

Comment: That's because the query is satisfied from the `covering index`. It looks directly for the index range (key1=123), and within that, the last item (max B) - single lookup and instant.